# Claims values returned null c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a completed project that I built using ASP.NET MVC and the project status is live.

It was created while I'm learning ASP.NET and now I hope to rebuild it again using new methods and new views to increase the system's efficiency.

So for this, I have created a new Solution and created a class library project, and Copied all the models from my past project.

Also created the new ASP.NET MVC project with the same solution.

My issue is after the successful login I'm adding some important access details to the `claims` and accessing those in other controllers.

When debugging the code it's successfully adding data to the claims but when I tried to read it returns as null.

I'm using the same code which I was used in my previous code and can't figure out why it happening.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();

try 
{  
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
    claims.Add(new Claim("UserId", userid));
    claims.Add(new Claim("UserLevel", UserLevel));
    
    var claimIdenties = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    
    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    
    var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
    
    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() {
        IsPersistent = isPersistent
    }, claimIdenties);
    
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
}
```

This is the controller code that I used to read the data from the claims. This returns null

```
var UsrLvl = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "UserLevel").FirstOrDefault();
string UsrLvlT = UsrLvl.Value;
```

Comment: What's your question? And can we get a [mcve]?

Comment: Don't assign the principal on `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. Assign it to `HttpContext.Current.User` instead.

Comment: @haim770 I tried using your suggestion. But the result is still the same. Value became null when reading. The thing is my project that is currently live using the same method but didn't get this error. It works fine and I copy-paste the same code. But here it wont work

Comment: @Enigmativity question is for ``UsrLvl`` It doesn't get the value from the claims.

Comment: Are you sure the cookie is correctly issued and the identity you get for authenticated users is **the** identity you issue from your owin middleware? My guess is your authentication just doesn't work and what you get is an empty, unauthenticated user without claims.

Comment: @DevBeginner - Yes, but what is your question? What are you asking us?

Comment: @Enigmativity: this looks ok to me, the OP question is why they can't read claims they put into the principal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this code

```
public static string GetClaimValue(HttpContext httpContext, string valueType)
{
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueType)) return null;
            var identity = httpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var valueObj = identity == null ? null : identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == valueType);
            return valueObj==null? null:valueObj.Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi any explained more details for your answer ??

Comment: I feel like I have to keep pointing this out: please don't drop code only answers. Provide an explanation for the solution. 4 out of 5 of your most recent answers have said "try this" or "I am using this code". You might think that's sufficient, but people come here when they don't understand why their code doesn't work. Just handing over working code without an explanation might help in some cases, but it really lowers the usefulness of the answer.

Comment: This looks like a safer version of what the OP already does. Just more safety checks. However, if their code doesn't work, this won't work as well, most probably.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Trust me,  it is not just a safe version. The extra code makes all the difference since this code usually runs several time before returning result.

Comment: Let's just wait for OPs comment, if this somehow works, you were right. If this doesn't work as their version, I was. It's not the matter of trust, I don't guess here, I work with claim code almost daily.